# Wordpress Inline Javascript Unescape

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Ok, so I have a feed which is used to create posts on Wordpress.

At the bottom of the content tag, there is a simple Google Analytics script which sends a page view to Google. This all works fine when there isn't an "'" in the title tag but when there is an "'" it gets unescaped.

The feed pipes down this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX', 'auto', {'name': 'feed'});
ga('feed.set', 'referrer', location.origin);
ga('feed.send', 'pageview', { 'location': location.href, 'page': (location.pathname + location.search + location.hash), 'title': 'This is my title \'with an \' in it'});
//--></script>
```

Which gets changed to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX', 'auto', {'name': 'feed'});
    ga('feed.set', 'referrer', location.origin);
    ga('feed.send', 'pageview', { 'location': location.href, 'page': (location.pathname + location.search + location.hash), 'title': 'This is my title 'with an ' in it'});
    //--></script>
```

Which obviously causes me a syntax error because of the title string.

I have kses set to allow script tags, and I can manually add in the escape character to the javascript string in the wordpress content editor.

I have also added a small debugger to the wp_insert_post() method which shows that the content is fine prior to the insert statement after being sanitized etc. But then straight after save is changed?

Is there a default after content save filter which could be causing me this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the code showing how the code is added to the content tag.

Comment: You need to double escape, it seems. So, where you have `\'` put `\\'`. That should work, hopefully.

Comment: @Todd interesting thought on the double escape. I'll look into that now

Comment: So i don't have access to change the feed so made a filter which I called on content_pre_save. A simple str_replace on the content for \' with \\' but this causes problems when resaving the post. Any ideas?

Comment: Hrmm. Try replacing with the html entity instead: `&quot;`

Comment: Or, since you're using single quotes, you could use `&#39;` instead.